# make a game that is featured as an xbox game

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I've seen a great deal of games on windows phone featuring the xbox mark and a lot not featuring it. I have some questions about that:

1) What is the difference between the 2 types of games? As i see it, i think that the xbox versions can award achievements for some tasks on the users xbox profile. Is there more?

2) How can one add a game to the marketplace and make it xbox-able?

Any tutorial or web source could be of great use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Xbox live approved, I think you have to work with Microsoft - you have to get your company approved - see http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/wp7 for more details.